# Как все единицы в двоичном представлении числа сдвинуть вправо используя только один цикл?

Tags: c++

Например: дано целое число, двоичное представление которого  0110'0011'0010, нужно получить целое число, двоичное представление которого 0000'0001'1111, используя только один цикл.
Желательно используя побитовые операции

Я придумал только примитивный вариант с подсчетом единиц и последующим выводом нужной последовательности

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <bitset>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    int y;
    cin >> y;
    int count = 0;
    unsigned int mask = 1;
    for (; mask > 0; mask = mask << 1) {
        if ((y & mask) == mask) {
            count += 1;
        }
    }
    string begin((32 - count), '0');
    string end(count, '1');
    cout << bitset<32>(y) << endl << endl;
    cout << begin << end;
    
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Так у вас число или строка? со строкой все очень просто — один цикл со счетчиками чтения и записи... В принципе, то же можно и с bitset

Comment: `2^n-1` содержит n единичек. *сначала считаете единички и потом выводите это число*

Comment: На входе целое число, я вывожу строку, то есть просто создаю видимость того, что сдвинул единицы, что не правильно

Comment: @AlexGlebe спасибо, но меня еще интересует, есть ли способ сделать это без подсчета единичек?

Comment: Быстро подсчитать число единичных бит -- [__builtin_popcount](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html) / Если надо самому, то нужно сделать табличку из 256 чисел с количеством единичных бит для каждого возможного значения байта и использовать каждый **байт числа как индекс** в ней

Comment: Если использовать для `y` тип `unsigned int`, то тогда можно без цикла: `#include <bit> ... unsigned res = y ? -1u >> std::popcount(~y) : y;`. Ну и ещё один вариант с циклом: `unsigned res = 0; for ( ; y; y >>= 1) if (y & 1u) res = (res << 1) | 1u; `.

Comment: Я не совсем понял, как работает метод без цикла, можете словами пояснить пожалуйста?

Comment: Функция `popcount` считает кол-во единичек. Битовое отрицание `~` инвертирует биты. Таким образом выражение `popcount(~y)` считает количество нулей в числе `y`. Число `-1u` состоит полностью из единичек. Сдвинув его на `popcount(~y)` битов вправо мы получим число, у которого в старших разрядах столько нулей, сколько их всего в числе `y`, а в младших разрядах столько единичек, сколько их всего в числе `y`. Тернарным оператором `? :` отдельно рассматриваем случай, когда `y == 0`, чтобы избежать сдвига на столько битов, сколько их всего в числе `-1u`. Правила языка запрещают такой большой сдвиг.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если буквально следовать заданию, то:

```
int j = 0; // результат в j
for (int k = 1; k != 0; k <<= 1) if ((y & k) != 0) j = (j << 1) | 1;
```

Написано на c#, но к c++ должно подойти, мне кажется.

**P. S.** Прямо сил нету терпеть - так хочется объединить две замечательные алгоритмические находки @StanislavVolodarskiy и @ARHovsepyan, ибо ни один из них не сможет этого сделать, не нарушая авторства другого:

```
#include <iostream>
int main() {
    unsigned x;
    std::cin >> x;
    unsigned y = 1;
    for (; x != 0; x &= x - 1) y <<= 1;
    std::cout << y - 1 << '\n';
}
```

Comment: В целом быстрее будет сдвигать `y` вправо,, пока не 0. А установить в j нужное количество бит в 1 можно и не в цикле -- `j = (1 << n)  - 1;` (n это количество найденных единичек)

Comment: @avp, если исходное число полностью состоит из единичек, то здесь `(1 << n)` будет UB.

Comment: @wololo, ну, на практике это бред, но перешлите его перед исследованием в `unsigned int` (это стандарт позволяет)

Comment: @avp, что именно бред?

Comment: @wololo, UB с int, естественно

Comment: @avp, [OK](https://godbolt.org/z/ee7GeGooM)

Answer (score 3):

Я считаю  `avp` прав, и можно учитывать замечание `wololo`, (хотя такие дотошные праверки искусственно разбухают код, и нужно учитывать специфику и предназначение кода. Например, в данном случаи, ввести из cin  число не имеющее нулевых битов, мягко говоря, из ряда  чудес):

```
int res = 1, n;   
cin >> n;
if(~n == 0) res = n;
else {  
    for (; n; n >>= 1) 
        if (n & 1)  res <<= 1;  
    res -= 1;
}
```

Comment: Я не совсем понимаю, почему ` res -= 1; ` ? В моем представлении это работает так:
(не буду весь диапазон int писать)`res = 0000'0001 << 1 == 0000'0010` потом `0000'0010 - 1 == 2 - 1 == 1 == 0000'0001` и нужно прибавлять каждый раз 1, а не отнимать. Пожалуйста, укажите на ошибку в моем рассуждении

Comment: не понял о чем вы, res -= 1; выполняется не в цикле, а после

Comment: Эта причина по которой я всегда пишу фигурные скобки.

Comment: Как будет работать код для `MAX_INT`?

Comment: Этот алгоритм `res <<= 1; } res -= 1;` тоже хорош!

Answer (score 3):

`x &= x - 1` стирает из `x` младший установленный бит. `y = (y << 1) | 1;` - добавляет бит в `y`. Цикл повторится столько раз, сколько бит  установленно в `x`. Столько же бит окажется в `y` в итоге:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    unsigned x;
    std::cin >> x;
    unsigned y = 0;
    for (; x != 0; x &= x - 1) {
        y = (y << 1) | 1;
    }
    std::cout << y << '\n';
}
```

**P.S.** Я сменил тип на `unsigned`. Но код будет рабочим если оставить тип `int`.

Comment: `Но будет рабочим и для если оставить тип int.` [Или не будет](https://godbolt.org/z/hnEhfcPbr).

Comment: @wololo, задача предполагает работу с неотрицательными числами.

Comment: Супер, вот это `x &= x - 1` оригинальный ход!